# how to retrieve image from database into picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void view_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {          
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SOFT;Initial Catalog=Dev01;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        //Retrieve BLOB from database into DataSet.
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from empdetails", con);
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            lbl_fname.Text = myReader["firstname"].ToString();
            lbl_mname.Text = myReader["middlename"].ToString();
            lbl_lname.Text = myReader["lastname"].ToString();
            lbl_gender.Text = myReader["gender"].ToString();
            lbl_dob.Text = myReader["dob"].ToString();   
            lbl_qualification.Text = myReader["qualification"].ToString();
            lbl_skills.Text = myReader["skills"].ToString();
            lbl_userid.Text = myReader["username"].ToString();
            lbl_pwd.Text = myReader["password"].ToString();
            lbl_cpwd.Text = myReader["confirmpassword"].ToString();
            lbl_mno.Text = myReader["mobilenumber"].ToString();
            lbl_altmno.Text = myReader["alternativenumber"].ToString();
            lbl_email.Text = myReader["email"].ToString();
            lbl_presentadd.Text = myReader["presentaddress"].ToString(); 
            lbl_permanentadd.Text = myReader["permanentaddress"].ToString();
        }

        myReader.Close();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "empdetails");
        int c = ds.Tables["empdetails"].Rows.Count;
        if (c > 0)
        { 
            //BLOB is read into Byte array, then used to construct MemoryStream,
            //then passed to PictureBox.
            //SqlCommand cmd1=new SqlCommand("Select photo from empdetails");
            Byte[] bytedata = new Byte[0];
            bytedata = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["empdetails"].Rows[c - 1]["photo"]);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytedata);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms,true); //HERE I AM GETTING ERROR
        }
        con.Close();  
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    }

}
```

I already checked various pages but that didn't solve my problem. I am getting an error only in this part:

```
"pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms,true);"
```

Comment: FYI, this is an English-only site, and "plz" is not an English word.

Answer (score 0):

The data type of your column should be `image` try

`public byte[] ConvertImageToByte(Image image, ImageFormat format)
    {
      var stream = new MemoryStream();
      image.Save(stream, format);
      return stream.ToArray();
    }`

 `public Image ConvertBytesToImage(object _image)
    {
      byte[] byteImage = (byte[])(_image);
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteImage);
      ms.Write(byteImage, 0, byteImage.Length);
      Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
      return img;
    }`

Saving the byte in your database

`OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
    file.Title = "Please Select the Employee Photo (Dimension 128x128)";
    file.Filter = "JPEG Files|*.jpg|Bitmap Files|*.bmp|Gif Files|*.gif|PNG Files|*.png";
    file.DefaultExt = "jpg";
    file.ShowDialog();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
    {
     byte[] bytePhoto = ConvertImageToBytes(Image.FromFile(file.FileName), ImageFormat.Png);
    //bytePhoto is the object to save in your database
    }`

Retrieve the byte and display as image

`byte[] bytePhoto = (byte[])ds.Tables["empdetails"].Rows[0]["Photo"];
    pictureBox1.Image = ConvertBytesToImage(bytePhoto);`